# How to organize two rows of equally sized buttons using MigLayout nested inside a ScrollPane

Tags: java, jframe, jscrollpane, miglayout

I am working with JFrame and am trying to design a container that can hold an array of buttons spread across 2 rows (and multiple columns).

I need to fit in as many buttons as I want. While having varying widths of text, the buttons themselves have to be of the same size (the text will have to wrap inside the button if it is larger than the width).

I am using a `JScrollPane`, and laying out my buttons using `MigLayout`.

This the code I have so far. I am new to MigLayout and there are so many options it got me confused really fast. I need help with setting the row/columns constraints so that I have only two rows (and the column number would be equal to half the array's size), and with setting the component constraints  so that each button has the same width and height and wrapping text.

I am adding the buttons manually here as I didn't get to implement it with an array yet.

**UPDATE**: I was able to figure out how to make the text wrap like I want to using HTML tags.

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "[300px]", "[150px]"));
    panel.setBounds(35, 377, 1294, 307);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 377, 1319, 341);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);

    JButton btnButton = new JButton("The dominoes will help you read what's written behind the board.");
    panel.add(btnButton, "cell 0 0,grow");

    JButton btnButton_1 = new JButton("What about the wooden box?");
    panel.add(btnButton_1, "cell 1 0,grow");

    JButton btnButton_2 = new JButton("Did you look at the stool?");
    panel.add(btnButton_2, "cell 2 0,grow");

    JButton btnButton_3 = new JButton("The dominoes will help you read what's written behind the board.");
    panel.add(btnButton_3, "cell 3 0,grow");

    JButton btnButton_4 = new JButton("The room is a clock.");
    panel.add(btnButton_4, "cell 4 0,grow");

    JButton btnButton_5 = new JButton("If 12:00 is the red dot, where is 6:05?");
    panel.add(btnButton_5, "cell 5 0,grow");

    JButton btnButton_6 = new JButton("Sunglasses are black.");
    panel.add(btnButton_6, "cell 0 1,grow");

    JButton btnButton_7 = new JButton("Are you sure you looked everywhere?");
    panel.add(btnButton_7, "cell 1 1,grow");

    JButton btnButton_8 = new JButton("The darts are color coded.");
    panel.add(btnButton_8, "cell 2 1,grow");

    JButton btnButton_9 = new JButton("Where else have you seen this pattern?");
    panel.add(btnButton_9, "cell 3 1,grow");

    JButton btnButton_10 = new JButton("Did you look are the wigs?");
    panel.add(btnButton_10, "cell 4 1,grow");

    JButton btnButton_11 = new JButton("Maybe they're page numbers?");
    panel.add(btnButton_11, "cell 5 1,grow");
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you know you have 2 rows and N columns. I suppose you know the number of total buttons that you need to add, you should divide by the number of rows to get the number of buttons by row.

After that, until you reach that number, you add your buttons this way:

```
while (anyCounter < totalButtonsByRow) {
    panel.add(btnButton_X, "grow");
    anyCounter++;
}
```

Take into account that when you reach the number of buttons in a row, add the last button this way:

```
panel.add(btnButton_X, "grow, wrap");
```

And at last, fill the second row with the rest of the buttons.

```
panel.add(btnButton_X, "grow");
```